# Is to inherit an entity class from another class/interface a right way?

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose I have two hibernate entity classes: `class Player` and `class Partner` which both will be participate in a mailing. That's they are both contain the following fields:

```
String email;

Integer id;

String name
```

I want to create an interface as follows:

```
public interface Recipient{

    public String getEmail();

    public String getName();

    public Integer getId();
}
```

Essentially, these classes will be something like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
class Player implements Recipient

 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ps_id")
    private String psId;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    //GET, SET and inherited method impl
}
```

This is the right way to do this or in hibernate shall not write an entity class, inherited one from another class/interface? `Just POJO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@MappedSuperclass` annotation on the interface class. AFAIK this is the right way to do it.

Comment: The thing is there are no needs to create an entity class. I just wanna create an interface to incapsulate column_name of my entities.

Comment: If you only want to put some getters, no need for the annotation. If you'll put some db fields, map them to columns then you'll need the annotation. You can check this link: 
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/MappedSuperclass

Comment: Interesting... As far as understand there is no need to map `@MappedSuperclass` entity to a database_table. We just define columns name which may be overriden latter. Right?

Comment: yes. you cant map a MappedSuperClass to a certain table but define fields and relations in it if you want. I'm not 100% certain if we can override them in subclasses